# zmq DEALER socket zmq_recv_msg call always timeouts

Tags: c++, sockets, zeromq

I am using `zmq` **`ROUTER`** and **`DEALER`** sockets in my application(`C++`).

One process is listening on zmq `ROUTER` socket for clients to connect (a Service).

Clients connect to this service using zmq `DEALER` socket. From the client I am doing synchronous (blocking) request to the service. To avoid the
infinite wait time for the response, I am setting **`RCVTIMEO`** on `DEALER` socket to let say 5 ms. After setting this timeout I observe un-expected
behaviour on the client.

Here are the details:

**Case 1: No `RCVTIMEO` is set on `DEALER` (client) socket**

In this case, let say client sends 1000 Request to the service. Out of these requests for around 850 requests, client receives responses within 5 ms.

For remaining 150 request it takes more than 5 ms for response to come.

**Case 2:  `RCVTIMEO` is set for 5 ms on `DEALER` (client) socket**

In this case, for the first 150-200 request I see valid response received within `RCVTIMEO` period. For all remaining requests I see `RCVTIMEO` timeout happening, which is not expected. The requests in both the cases are same.

**The expected behiour should be**: for 850 requests we should receive valid response (as they are coming within `RCVTIMEO`). And for remaining 150
requests we should see a timeout happening.

For having the timeout feature, I tried **`zmq_poll()`** also instead of setting `RCVTIMEO`, but results are same. Most of the requests are getting TIMEDOUT.

I went through the zmq documentation for details, but didn't find anything.

Can someone please explain the reason for this behaviour ?

Comment: I have experienced version incompabilities with the c++ implementation and the latest version of zeroMQ. So, try the zguide C code togheter with the latest zeroMQ version and check if you experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @user2745813 you might already know, that StackOverflow executes an **`MCVE`**-code policy for posting Questions. Would you consider adding and update with such a **`M`**-inimum **`C`**-omplete **`V`**-erifiable **`E`**-xample of code, which is run-able and which replicates the issue you are facing? That would be exactly what StackOverflow defined in the Community Nettiquette as a part of the desired professional Community habit. **Anyway, enjoy this great Community and become active, contributing member among of thic gang of knowledge supported by people all around the globe**